# Call the same function with two different types from a when condition

Tags: kotlin, switch-statement, extension-methods

I was wondering if it was possible to group a call to a function that is present for two different types, without having to create two branches in the "when" statement.

For example, in my case I have this class extensions:

```kotlin
// File: PublisherExtensions.kt

fun <T> Mono<T>.toServiceResponse(): Mono<Response<T>> =
    this.map { r -> Response(true, r, null) }
        .onErrorResume { e -> Mono.just(Response(false, null, Response.Error(500, e.message))) }

fun <T> Flux<T>.toServiceResponse(): Mono<Response<List<T>>> =
    this.collectList()
        .map { r -> Response(true, r, null) }
        .onErrorResume { e -> Mono.just(Response(false, null, Response.Error(500, e.message))) }
```

And what I use with them is this statement:

```kotlin
val body = when (val value = result.returnValue) {
    is Mono<*> -> value.toServiceResponse()
    is Flux<*> -> value.toServiceResponse()
    else -> throw RuntimeException("The \"body\" should be Mono<*> or Flux<*>!")
}
```

While what I would like would be this:

```kotlin
val body = when (val value = result.returnValue) {
    is Mono<*>, is Flux<*> -> value.toServiceResponse()
    else -> throw RuntimeException("The \"body\" should be Mono<*> or Flux<*>!")
}
```

The IDE gives me this error:

> Unresolved reference.
> None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
>
> - public fun  Flux<TypeVariable(T)>.toServiceResponse(): Mono<Response<List<TypeVariable(T)>>> defined in brc.studybuddy.backend.wrapper.util in file PublisherExtensions.kt
> - public fun  Mono<TypeVariable(T)>.toServiceResponse(): Mono<Response<TypeVariable(T)>> defined in brc.studybuddy.backend.wrapper.util in file PublisherExtensions.kt

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: @lukas.j yes, i've edit the question with the error it gives to me

Comment: I doubt that this is related to combining two branches of the _when_. Are you sure you're not getting the same error when having separate branches?

Comment: @lukas.j yes, using separate branches it works

Comment: What you would like is not possible. It seems like you just want to reduce code duplication here. How about rewriting it in a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the second `toServiceResponse` can be defined in terms of the first:

```
fun <T> Flux<T>.toServiceResponse(): Mono<Response<List<T>>> =
    this.collectList().toServiceResponse()
```

So you are almost doing the same thing on `Mono`s and `Flux`es, except that for `Flux`es, you also call `collectList` first.

```
val body = when (val value = result.returnValue) {
    is Mono<*> -> value
    is Flux<*> -> value.collectList()
    else -> throw RuntimeException("The \"body\" should be Mono<*> or Flux<*>!")
}.toServiceResponse()
```

Alternatively, without a `when`:

```
val body = result.returnValue.let { value ->
    (value as? Flux<*>)?.collectList() 
    ?: (value as? Mono<*>)
    ?: throw RuntimeException("The \"body\" should be Mono<*> or Flux<*>!")
}.toServiceResponse()
```